# Segmenting a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-mining

Given a CSV dataset with Dates and Values, I want to try and create a new CSV dataset,in which the output consists of points where the graph has changed: increase, decrease or not changed at all.There is a following example from the data, and the desired output. (the CSV goes down to the year of 1999)

```
Date        Value
07/04/2014  137209.0
04/04/2014  137639.0
03/04/2014  137876.0
02/04/2014  137795.0
01/04/2014  137623.0
31/03/2014  137589.0
28/03/2014  137826.0
27/03/2014  138114.0
26/03/2014  138129.0
25/03/2014  137945.0
```

output should be:

```
StartDate   EndDate   StartValue   EndValue
03/04/2014  07/04/2014  137876      137209
31/03/2014  03/04/2014  137589      137876
27/03/2014  31/03/2014  138114      137589
26/03/2014  27/03/2014  138129      138114
25/03/2014  26/03/2014  137945      138129
```

Comment: What did your do to code a solution? On what basis are you grouping ? Strectches  of pure increase, pure decrease or pure stagnation? Is your csv data sorted? Whay do you have duplicate datapoints (f.e. 3/4/ occures twice as start and endpoint of a pure decrease/pure increase stretch)?#

Comment: I did a cleanup, got rid of NULL rows, and created the empty new CSV with the desired 4 columns. Yea, I'm grouping stretches of pure increase and decrease. the CSV input is sorted by Date column, as being shown in the example above, and it goes down to the year of 1999.

Comment: Interesting puzzle - there is probably somthing in pandas or numpy that can deal with ít in 4 lines, unfortunately you havent used those tags so ppl good in it won't see this. If I were you, I would remove the `data-*` tags, they do you no good, better add numpy/pandas.

Comment: Yea thanks for letting me know, my main use is with Pandas and Numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sign` from `numpy` and apply it to the `diff` on the column 'Value' to see where the trend of the graph changes and then create an incremental value for each group of trend with `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
ser_sign = np.sign(df.Value.diff(-1).ffill())
ser_gr = ser_gr =(ser_sign.shift() != ser_sign).cumsum()
```

Now you know the groups, to get the start and end of each of them, you can use `groupby` on the `ser_gr`, `join` the `last` (after `shift` the value in `ser_gr` as the last of each group is the first of the next one) and the `first`.

```
df_new = (df.groupby(ser_gr.shift().bfill(),as_index=False).last()
            .join(df.groupby(ser_gr,as_index=False).first(),lsuffix='_start',rsuffix='_end'))

print (df_new)
   Date_start  Value_start    Date_end  Value_end
0  03/04/2014     137876.0  07/04/2014   137209.0
1  31/03/2014     137589.0  03/04/2014   137876.0
2  26/03/2014     138129.0  31/03/2014   137589.0
3  25/03/2014     137945.0  26/03/2014   138129.0
```

Now if you need to reorder the columns and rename them, you can do it with:

```
df_new.columns = ['StartDate', 'StartValue', 'EndDate', 'EndValue']
df_new = df_new[['StartDate','EndDate','StartValue','EndValue']]

print (df_new)
    StartDate     EndDate  StartValue  EndValue
0  03/04/2014  07/04/2014    137876.0  137209.0
1  31/03/2014  03/04/2014    137589.0  137876.0
2  26/03/2014  31/03/2014    138129.0  137589.0
3  25/03/2014  26/03/2014    137945.0  138129.0
```

These two operations could be done at the same time than you create `df_new` using `rename`.

Comment: as I thought ... not quite a  4 liner but 6 .. and  neat - at least you come to the same results as I do ;) regarding the grouping

Comment: @PatrickArtner Indeed, few lines are enough :) thanks. Actually I'm glad you answered before as I get the same grouping, I was more confident on this result.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess the sign option from Numpy is what I needed, and that is the step that was missing in my process. Thank you @PatrickArtner for your enriching approach.

Answer (score 3):

My try to solve that, involving a selfwritten `Stretch` class that manages the splitting of your data when adding them:

```
from enum import Enum

class Direction(Enum):
    NA = None 
    Up = 1 
    Stagnant = 0 
    Down = -1

    @staticmethod
    def getDir(a,b):
        """Gets two numbers and returns a Direction result by comparing them."""
        if a < b:   return Direction.Up
        elif a > b: return Direction.Down
        else:       return Direction.Stagnant

class Stretch:
    """Accepts tuples of (insignificant, float). Adds tuples to internal data struct
    while they have the same trend (down, up, stagnant). See add() for details."""

    def __init__(self,dp=None):
        self.data = []
        if dp:
            self.data.append(dp)
        self.dir = Direction.NA  


    def add(self,dp):
        """Adds dp to self if it follows a given trend (or it holds less then 2 datapts).
        Returns (True,None) if the datapoint was added to this Stretch instance,
        returns (False, new_stretch) if it broke the trend. The new_stretch
        contains the new last value of the self.data as well as the new dp."""
        if not self.data:
            self.data.append(dp)
            return True, None
        if len(self.data) == 1:
            self.dir = Direction.getDir(self.data[-1][1],dp[1]) 
            self.data.append(dp)
            return True, None
        if Direction.getDir(self.data[-1][1],dp[1]) == self.dir:
            self.data.append(dp)
            return True, None
        else:
            k = Stretch(self.data[-1])
            k.add(dp)
            return False, k
```

Demo-File:

```
with open("d.txt","w") as w:
    w.write( """Date        Value
07/04/2014  137209.0
04/04/2014  137639.0
03/04/2014  137876.0
02/04/2014  137795.0
01/04/2014  137623.0
31/03/2014  137589.0
28/03/2014  137826.0
27/03/2014  138114.0
26/03/2014  138129.0
25/03/2014  137945.0
""" )
```

Usage:

```
data_stretches = []

with open("d.txt") as r:
    S = Stretch()
    for line in r:
        try:
            date,value = line.strip().split()
            value = float(value)
        except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
            print("Illegal line: '{}'".format(line))
            continue

        b, newstretch = S.add( (date,value) )
        if not b:
            data_stretches.append(S)
            S = newstretch
data_stretches.append(S)

for s in data_stretches:
    data = s.data
    direc = s.dir


    print(data[0][0], data[-1][0], data[0][1],data[-1][-1], s.dir)
```

Output:

```
# EndDate  StartDate  EndV     StartV   (reversed b/c I inverted dates)  
07/04/2014 03/04/2014 137209.0 137876.0 Direction.Up
03/04/2014 31/03/2014 137876.0 137589.0 Direction.Down
31/03/2014 26/03/2014 137589.0 138129.0 Direction.Up
26/03/2014 25/03/2014 138129.0 137945.0 Direction.Down
```

Beside the jumble of the direction based on "from when to when" you evaluate the data, my output is different to yours ... because you split a uniform sequence into two parts w/o obvious reason:

> ```
> 27/03/2014  31/03/2014  138114      137589   # further down
> 26/03/2014  27/03/2014  138129      138114   # down
> ```

Comment: thanks very much! It was very interesting approach to my problem, and I learnt quite a few new stuff.